# How can I delete files by extension in subfolders of a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have a folder, which contains many subfolders, each containing some videos and .srt files. I want to loop over the main folder so that all the .srt files from all subfolders are deleted.

Here is something I tried-

```
    import sys
    import os
    import glob

    main_dir = '/Users/Movies/Test'

    folders = os.listdir(main_dir)

    for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(main_dir):
       for file in files:
          if file.endswith('.srt'):
          os.remove(file)
```

However, I get an error as follows-

```
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.srt'
```

Is there any way I can solve this? I am still a beginner so sorry I may have overlooked something obvious.

Comment: python doesn't know where `'file1.srt'` is, you need to tell it to remove `'/Users/Movies/Test/file1.srt'` instead

Comment: @SuperStew Nope, it also won't work. The error happens because you don't change directory while walking with `os.walk`. So python searches for the file in the current directory. See [Matt L.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821192/13123836)'s answer.

Comment: @Asocia you dont need to change the working directory to delete a file. Absolute paths work for that, which is what Matt L's answer is saying...

Comment: I mean `os.walk` just returns paths, so when you try to delete a file with it's name directly, you should change your working directory to that directory the file belongs.

Comment: I'm trying to say that just appending `file_name` to `main_dir` will not work everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the filename with the location.

```
import sys
import os
import glob

main_dir = '/Users/Movies/Test'

folders = os.listdir(main_dir)

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk(main_dir):
   for file in files:
      if file.endswith('.srt'):
          source_file = os.path.join(dirname, file)
          os.remove(source_file)
```